# Adding bar charts to maps in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, chart

When it comes to Symbology, is there a way of showing bar charts on the maps or at least in a layout in ArcGIS Pro?

This was possible in ArcMap and so I am just wondering if this is still a feasible task in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1):

[Bar Charts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/bar-chart.htm) appear in the ArcGIS Pro online help.

However, these too do not seem to be about placing bar charts (or pie charts) on features using the Symbology of a layer like you can in ArcMap.

Doing that does not appear in the [ArcGIS Pro Roadmap](https://community.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro/blog/2018/02/02/arcgis-pro-roadmap).

If these are important for you to have in ArcGIS Pro I recommend that you look for, or submit, an ArcGIS Idea to vote on.